# problem installing visual studio 2010 service pack 1 after uninstall

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I installed visual studio 2010 service pack 1 and uninstalled it.
Now I need to install it again and the installer says

> Requisitos de instalación:
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 no se puede instalar porque el estado de este equipo no lo admite. Para obtener instrucciones sobre cómo corregir el problema, consulte el archivo léame del sitio web del Centro de descarga de Microsoft.

In english is  something like:

> Installation requirements:
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Service Pack 1 cannot be installed because this pc does not allowed it. To obtain instructions to correct the problem, please read the read me file from Microsoft download center.

The link which appears in the screen is http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/default.aspx, but I think they mean http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509/en-us.

Do I need to uninstall visual studio?

Comment: Please provide full error message

Comment: Visual Studio service packs are a crapshoot; probably easier to just reinstall Visual Studio entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct document is actually obtained from the ReadMe of the original SP1 download site:

- http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210711

See:

- 2.2. Uninstalling, and
- 2.2.1. If Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 is uninstalled, Visual Studio 2010 must be reinstalled to restore certain components